# Appending dynamic value to ruby instance variable

Tags: ruby

I know this code doesn't look good at all , but i just want to explain my requirement. I want to know is there any good or alternative approach to it.

Actually, i want to create a new stack and whenever one stack has reached its capacity. I want to keep track of number of stacks created like `@stack_1`, `@stack_2` ...by incrementing `@number += 1` like `@stack_@number`. And for every stack, i want to maintain a `@current_position` pointer which is specific to every stack like `@stack_2` has `@current_position_2`. So i want to create dynamic instance variables.

**Example:**

```
def initialize
  @number = 1
  @stack+"#{@number}" = Array.new(10)
  @current_position_"#{@number}" = 0
end
```

Output should be something like `@stack1 = Array.new(10)`. 

Lets say if i increment value of `@number += 1`, it should look like `@stack2 = Array.new(10)`

Comment: Could you explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: hi @Stefan , added more info to the question on what i want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
instance_variable_set("@stack#{@number}", Array.new(10, :a))
@stack1
  #=> [:a, :a, :a, :a, :a, :a, :a, :a, :a, :a]

instance_variable_set("@stack#{@number+1}", Array.new(10, :b))
@stack2
  #=> [:b, :b, :b, :b, :b, :b, :b, :b, :b, :b]

instance_variable_set("@current_position_#{@number}", 0)
@current_position_1
  #=> 0
```

Comment: how to achieve for @current_position_"#{@number}" = 0 ? which is not an instance_variable

Comment: Does the last addition answer your question?

Comment: yep..so can i use both `@stack1` and `@current_position_1` regularly in my programs ?

Comment: Yes, just as though you defined them in the normal way.

Comment: how to go in situation like `if @current_position_@number < @stack@number.size`

Comment: If the name is created dynamically, and you don't know what it will be in advance, if it is held in a variable `var`, you can get its value with `instance_variable_get(var)`.  For example, `@cat = 9; var = "@cat"; instance_variable_get(var) #=> 9`.  So here, the right side of your inequality would be `instance_variable_get("@stack#{number}").size`. The docs are [Object#instance_variable_set](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_set) and [Object#instance_variable_get](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_get).

Comment: Thank you ..it worked good. Can you explain when exactly to use `instance_variable_set`, `instance_variable_get` ?

Comment: That's too big of a question to address in a comment. You could post that as a new question, but readers would probably say it is too broad of a question for SO. I need to leave now, so I won't be able to reply to any more comments until tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of array I suggest you to use Hash Map

```
@stack = Hash.new

@stack[@number] = <Your Array>
```

Be Careful if the @number is same your array will be replaced..

For more information about hash maps http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html

Comment: can you explain why to use hash instead of array ? ..my requirement is to create many stacks. Does hash act like place holder for all stacks ?

Comment: @RahulSambari yes.. it will

Comment: ill try to fit this suggestion into my scenario and let you know

Comment: hey, i updated my question.. lets say i want to maintain a position pointer for every stack..how to go about it

Comment: i liked this approach ..but how to maintain @current_position_@number in this scenario ?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating instance variables to track a stack's state from the outside, you could create a `Stack` class that tracks its state internally. Here's a very simple one:

```
class StackOverflow < StandardError; end

class Stack
  def initialize
    @stack = []
  end

  def position
    @stack.size
  end

  def full?
    position == 2 # small size for demonstration purposes
  end

  def push(obj)
    raise StackOverflow if full?
    @stack << obj
  end
end

stack = Stack.new
stack.push "foo"
stack.full?       #=> false

stack.push "bar"
stack.full?       #=> true

stack.push "baz"  #=> StackOverflow
```

Having a working stack, you can build something like a `StackGroup` to handle multiple stacks:

```
class StackGroup
  attr_reader :stacks

  def initialize
    @stacks = [Stack.new]
  end

  def push(obj)
    @stacks << Stack.new if @stacks.last.full?
    stacks.last.push(obj)
  end
end

stack_group = StackGroup.new
stack_group.push "foo"
stack_group.push "bar"
stack_group.stacks.size #=> 1

stack_group.push "baz"  # no error here
stack_group.stacks.size #=> 2

stack_group.stacks
#=> [#<Stack:0x007f9d8b886b18 @stack=["foo", "bar"]>,
#    #<Stack:0x007f9d8b886a50 @stack=["baz"]>]
```

Comment: i am sorry, but somehow .. i am little confused with your approach. Can you add some comments or is there any easy way to dynamically add numbers to instance variables ? it would be really helpful.

Comment: @RahulSambari there's no need for dynamically created instance variables here. `stack_groups` tracks and crates the stacks and each stack tracks its position. `stack_groups.stacks.size` returns the total number of stacks, `stack_groups.stacks[0].position` returns the first stack's position, `stack_groups.stacks[1].position` returns the second stack's position and so on.